# Selecting relevant data in a large sample Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have 8 sheets with data from an experiment, each sheet has 2500 measurements. I want to select only 50 measures from each sheet to make a relevant analysis. Considering the values measured in each experiment has two quantities being measured (in the case, electric tension and time) and these vary in equal increments in an interval of one of the quantities (time), how do I select 50 of them from the sample, if I want the reduced sample to have equal increments in the same interval of time (the quantity that follow this rule in the full sample) ? Doing it manually seems to be unpractical.

Comment: I know that when you are viewing your own data, what you write to explain it seems clear. But from "out here," there really is no way to understand what you are trying to do without seeing actual data in context. 

If you create a copy of your sheet, then use the File > Share option, being sure to choose "Anyone with the link can View...", you can post that link here and I'm sure get the help you need.

Comment: you could pass all the sheets into an array then pass a function/formula to get your desired result? maybe a `query`, `filter` or even a `pivot`? agree with Erik however.